# how to load ALL startup items before logging in to windows 8 desktop?

Tags: windows-8, boot, login

I am the only user of my laptop and the only reason i use a password is to prevent theft.

the quirk that i have with logon passwords is that the startup items will only load after i have keyed in the password.

is it possible to get win8 pro x64 to load all the startup items while it is still at the logon screen, so that it is ready for use immediately after i key in the password?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [autologon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx) to autologon your account. Now create a scheduled task which runs at logon (configure the trigger correctly) and locks the PC with the command:

```
rundll32.exe User32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

*Rundll32.exe is the program you select and add the other 2 values to parameter.*

When you now start the PC, Windows runs all startup tools but locks the PC and you have to enter the password. After you entered the password, Windows has all tools started for you.

Comment: Interesting workaround.  Does this immediately lock the PC on startup?  Or does it have to wait till all the applications are loaded?

Comment: Windows runs scheduled tasks with a lower priority, so there maybe a small gap before the locks screen occur, but the tools should start fine in background.

Comment: well, I +1'd it.  Its a working answer to the OPs issue and it meets the requirements.  However, I think its a small security risk. But the reality is, nothing is gained.  If he logs on and waits for his programs to start it will take X number of seconds.  If he applies your answer, the same number of seconds elapse, he just might not be sitting there waiting for it while booting.  Nitpicking, but my 2 cents.

Comment: sorry for the newbie question - but how do i add a scheduled task that can allow command input? or do  i just create a .bat with the command you just mentioned, and throw it into the startup folder of win8?

Comment: what do you mean with input? Here are the steps to create the task: http://techdows.com/2012/11/manage-schedule-tasks-windows-8.html

Comment: But, but... wouldn't that scheduled task lock the machine every time you login (making it impossible to login for more then a second)?

Comment: @Ben I haven't tried it. Play a bit with it and see if and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to lock the PC immediately on startup while loading windows/startup items in the background. This works with Windows editions that has group policy editor.

Step 1: Open notepad, then paste this code:

> WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("rundll32
>   user32.dll,LockWorkStation")

Step 2: Click `File>Save As` and in `Save as type` dropdown menu, choose `All Files`

Step 3: In the `File Name` field, enter `LockWorkStation.vbs` and save the file to `C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents`

Step 4: Hit `WindowsKey+R`, type `regedit` and press `ENTER`

Step 5: Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Step 6: Right Click on a blank space and click `New> DWORD (32-bit) Value` and press `ENTER`

Step 7: Double click the newly created `REG_DWORD` file. In the `Value name` type `RunLogonScriptSync` and in the `Value data` type`1` and then press `ENTER`

Step 8: Hit `WindowsKey+R`, type `gpedit.msc` and press `ENTER`

Step 9: Under `Computer Configuration`, go to 
 `Administrative Templates > System > Logon` then Double Click `Run these programs at user logon`

Step 10: Click `Enabled`, and on `Items to run at logon` click `Show...`

Step 11: Type `C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\LockWorkStation.vbs` and click `OK` repeatedly until all windows are closed

Step 12: Hit `WindowsKey+R` and type `control.exe userpasswords2` then press `ENTER`

Step 13: Uncheck `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.` then click `OK` (type in your password if it prompts to do so)

Step : Restart your PC.

Now whenever you start your PC, the .vbs script will run first before anything else. This will ensure that your PC is locked before the desktop appears.

*Note: You can change `C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\` to wherever you want to store your script.*